# How to affect memory allocated by new and casted to an array od class objects?

Tags: c++, c

I had hard time describing it in the title, but basically I have to turn some code from C based on structures into C++ one based on objects. At the beginnig it was more or less (I'll try to simplify since it's a part of a big library-like project):

```
typedef struct Thing{
int param;
char* name;
void* data;  //Either some arrays or more structures, hence void*
};

Thing* Initialise(void){
Thing* thing;
thing = (Thing*)malloc(sizeof(*thing));
param = 0;
name = NULL;
data = NULL;
return thing;
}

Thing* thing1 = malloc(bytesofdata);
Thing** smallthings = (Thing**) thing1->data; //Basically if "data" is a structure of other things
for ( i = 0; i < numberofsmallthings; i++ ) {
     size_t k;
     for ( k = 0; k < fieldsperthing; k++ ) {
          smallthings[i*fieldsperthing+k] = Initialise();
     }
}
```

Then I turned the structure into a class and the function into its method which resulted in:

```
class Thing{
private:
int param;
char* name;
void* data;  //Either some arrays or more structures, hence void*
public:
int Initialise(void);
};

int Thing::Initialise(void){
this->param = 0;
this->name = NULL;
this->data = NULL;
}

thing1->data = new Thing;
this->data = new char [bytesofdata];
Thing** smallthings = (Thing**)this->data;
for (i = 0; i < numberofsmallthings; i++) {
        size_t k;
        for (k = 0; k < fieldsperthing; k++) {
            smallthings[i*fieldsperthing + k]->Initialise();
        }
    }
```

And in this version, no matter if I try initialising the memory of not I am greeted by "access violation".
Is there any way to make this work? Casting to structure seemed to work fine so my guess is that something about objects makes it not work but I have no idea how to potentially bypass this. I would like to avoid making more objects since due to this part being buried pretty deep in functions, deleting those would be quite hard (especially since it's supposed to be a data reading function so exact structure of "data" might be not known).

Comment: What is your `Thing`, in the C++ version? Unfortunately, because the code you showed completely failed to meet the requirements for a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], it's not possible for anyone to help you. For more information see [ask].

Comment: The first example is also wrong, you use `thing1->data` which is uninitialized

Comment: BTW you should be writing the functionality in good C++, not doing some sort of line by line translation, that will just result in garbage code.  (And in case you are unaware , it's not necessary to make any changes in the first place if the original code is working).  So you will need to give a good description of the functionality you are trying to implement, in particular what `data` is

Comment: Added the class mockup. @M.M the data thing was my slip up, now hopefull corrected. And when it comes to functionality, I simply had to turn whole library into an object based version (so classes and methods). Data can contain either arrays of numbers or arrays of similar Thing objects (it's basically supposed to be a structure).

Comment: How do you know what sort of "data" is in any particular Thing

Comment: @M.M In the full version of code there is an enum that informs about data type (and is read from a binary file before the part I mentioned). I (I suppose wrongly) assumed it's not needed in this example, since the problems happen only with nested objects.

Comment: Well it is kind of important since the possible data types for the data affects how you should design the container

Comment: _"I had hard time describing it in the title," -- I would not worry much about that, since the title is just there to grab the attention of those who might know the answer. I would worry more about describing your question *in the question*. Better than posting before- and after- code would be describing (with words) what you did. Try to describe the situation, what you tried, and why you think it should have worked. Relegate the code to being a backup explanation, rather than primary. (See also [ask].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
smallthings[i*fieldsperthing + k]->Initialise();
```

You're attempting to dereference an unintialized pointer.  You first need to assign something to it, then you can initialize it:

```
smallthings[i*fieldsperthing + k] = new Thing;
smallthings[i*fieldsperthing + k]->Initialise();
```

Better yet, change `Initialise` to a constructor.  Then you won't have to do creation and initialization in separate steps.  So now you have:

```
int Thing::Thing(){
    this->param = 0;
    this->name = NULL;
    this->data = NULL;
}

...

    thing1 = new Thing();
    this->data = (void *)new Thing *[numberofsmallthings];
    Thing** smallthings = (Thing**)this->data;
    for (i = 0; i < numberofsmallthings; i++) {
        size_t k;
        for (k = 0; k < fieldsperthing; k++) {
            smallthings[i*fieldsperthing + k] = new Thing();
        }
    }
```